# Using Action link with Web Api Controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, actionlink

How can I use ActionLink when calling an action on a controller that is a WebApi controller.

```
public class RequestController : ApiController
{

    [ActionName("CreateAction")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Request))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostRequest(Request request)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Requests.Add(request);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = request.Id }, request);
    }

}
```

in my layout page can I do this

@Html.ActionLink("Request", "CreateAction", "api/Request", new { area = "" }, null)

Jawahar

Comment: there is no view in web api. You cannot do it, this is not what web api is designed for.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a link to an API controller using the standard Url helper property. The following link will point to an Albums controller and pass along an id parameter with a value of 3:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute=true, controller="Albums", id=3})
```

Please refer to this link
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/27/webapi-tip-5-generating-links.aspx